# Is IF(AND(OR... formula's in excel 2010 possible?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, nested-loops, nested-if

I have the formula below based on some threads from this thread but **I am getting an error.**

```
IF(AND(OR(G894=2,G894=2),OR(F894=2,F894=2),"Mete","Irrelevant"))
```

Any solution would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced a parenthesis. Remove this:

```
IF(AND(OR(G894=2,G894=2),OR(F894=2,F894=2),"Mete","Irrelevant"))
                                                              ^
```

And put it here:

```
IF(AND(OR(G894=2,G894=2),OR(F894=2,F894=2)),"Mete","Irrelevant")
                                          ^
```

Otherwise, you have:

```
AND(OR(G894=2,G894=2),OR(F894=2,F894=2),"Mete","Irrelevant")
```

As the expression and no parameters for the IF's true (or false) evaluation.